# How to find a Docker image tag with the same image ID by awk?

Tags: shell, awk

What I want to find is an image tag that has the same image ID with the latest container.

Here's the output of `docker images`

```
my/repository/service        migrate          6b061c3afc8c        5 weeks ago         887MB
my/repository/service        latest           6b061c3afc8c        5 weeks ago         887MB
my/repository/service        v3-arm64         6b061c3afc8c        5 weeks ago         887MB
```

I wrote a pretty complex method with two commands to solve this problem.

```sh
image_id=$(docker images | awk '{if ($1 == "my/repository/service" && $2 == "latest") {print $3}}')
docker images | awk -v lvar=$image_id '{if ($1 == "my/repository/service" && $2 != "migrate" && $2 != "latest" && $3 == lvar) { print $2 }}'
```

For the above example, the result I want to obtain is "v3-arm64".

Is there a better solution may be a single `awk` is enough?

Comment: I am just wondering how come ids are same in your docker images output

Comment: It's not clear why v3-arm64 should be the latest result?

Comment: @AkshayHegde `docker tag my/repository/service:v3-arm64 my/repository/service:latest`

Comment: @RamanSailopal it's not the latest result, the above output is just an example

Comment: Yeah but they are all 5 weeks old, so how do you decide which one is the "latest"?

Comment: @RamanSailopal `latest` tag is just a tag, it could be any other tags as well.

Comment: @RamanSailopal I re-read my question and found that I missed the word `same` before the image Id in the first sentence. Sorry for the misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment, adding more Generic solution here, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
your_command | 
awk '
$1=="my/repository/service" && ($2!="migrate" && $2!="latest"){
  if(prev==""){
    value=$2
    check=$3
  }
  else{
    if($1=="my/repository/service" && $3==prev && ($2!="migrate" && $2!="latest")){
      print $2
    }
  }
  next
}
$1=="my/repository/service" && $2=="latest"{
  if(check==$3){
      print value
  }
  else{
      prev=$3
  }
}'
```

---

---

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples and attempts only.

```
your_command | 
awk '
  $1=="my/repository/service" && $2=="latest"{
    prev=$3
    next
  }
  $1=="my/repository/service" && $3==prev && ($2!="migrate" && $2!="latest"){
    print $2
    prev=""
  }
'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
your_command |        ##Running OP docker command and sending output as input to awk code.
awk '                 ##Starting awk program from here.
  $1=="my/repository/service" && $2=="latest"{
                      ##Checking if 1st field is my/repository/service AND 2nd field is latest
    prev=$3           ##Then creating prev with value of 3rd column.
    next              ##next will skip further statements from here.
  }
  $1=="my/repository/service" && $3==prev && ($2!="migrate" && $2!="latest"){
                      ##Checking if 1st field my/repository/service AND 3rd field is equal to prev AND 2nd field is NOT equal to migrate AND latest then do following.
    print $2          ##Printing 2nd field whihc is the tag.
    prev=""           ##Nullifying prev here.
  }
'
```

Comment: Once OP confirms that this code is working for OP, I will add detailed explanation for above too.

Comment: It's working, thanks. Can you explain how it works

Comment: I have probably understood. But is the `prev=""` redundant in this context?

Comment: @BlaiseWang, yeah that is for safer side I added if after `latest` only one line is there then you need not to use it.  I have added detailed explanation for code above too, kindly do let me know in case of any queries cheers.

Comment: I do find that the order matters for your solution. In the case of `v3-arm64` is before the `latest`, your solution will not work. Can you edit your solution to make the order is irrelevant?

Comment: @BlaiseWang, ok so `v3-arm64` may come before `latest` also? Sorry it was not shown in samples, let me fix it. Could you please explain it should be 1 line above OR 1 line below `v3-arm64`?

Comment: `v3-arm64` may several lines before or below the `latest`. A general solution would be better.

Comment: sorry for the late confirmation, your answer works, thanks.

Comment: @BlaiseWang, Your welcome, keep learning and keep sharing on this great site, cheers.